# Family of Conformal Surface Parametrizations

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, conformal-geometry

Consider functions of the type $f(u,v) : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ representing a conformal parametrization of a surface.

Is there a family of closed-form functions (e.g. polynomials, trigonometric) that represents a variety of surfaces while preserving conformality?

Ideally, the family of functions would be general enough to represent any conformal mapping. I tried to frame this problem as a system of PDEs based on the first fundamental form of $f$, but it is severely underdetermined, so I am not sure if that is possible. Any pointers/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The parametrization of the sphere you gave is not conformal at all! What do you mean by "pretty much" conformal?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood something then. I thought it was conformal since $F = \langle f_u, f_v \rangle = 0$ and $E = G = \langle f_u, f_u \rangle = \langle f_v, f_v \rangle$. I mentioned "pretty much" because it does not cover the whole sphere. Am I missing something?

Comment: You'd better recompute $E$ and $G$ !!

Comment: You are right! Let me remove the example then, it is not the point of the question. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Is there even a general family of closed-form formulas for all conformal mappings $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, let alone $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: I don't think so, but I am not a specialist in this field. That's why I am looking for a family that covers a subset of the conformal mappings.